# norm of $AUx$ for unitary $U$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

> Let $U$ be a unitary matrix. Does it mean that for every invertible matrix $A$, $$\Vert AUx\Vert \le \Vert Ax\Vert$$ for every vector $x$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Suppose that we're working on $\mathbb{C}^2$ and that$$U=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }A=\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$Then, if $x=(1,0)$, $\|Ax\|=1$, whereas $\|AUx\|=2$.